# Why does excision for higher homotopy groups work? Is it a miracle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

If I understand correctly, homotopy groups behave well under products, and so it's reasonable that fiber bundles give long exact sequences.

What is weird to me is why there is even an analog of excision for higher homotopy groups. For homology it makes sense that $H(X,A) \cong H(X/A)$, because heuristically we imagine refining everything so simplexes lie in a small nbr of $A$ or a nbr of a complement. However, while I follow the proof of the homotopy excision theorem, the resulting  $\pi_n(X,A) \cong \pi_n(X/A)$ theorem is weird; it has a bunch of conditions on $A, (X,A)$ being very simply connected for it to work, which hints it is somewhat unnatural.

Is there a better frame-work to view the homotopy excision?

Comment: One can phrase the stability of homotopy groups of $S^n$ as saying that the loop space of $S^{n+1}$ has a model which has $S^n$ as an (2n)-skeleton, but has cells in higher dimensions. This seems reasonable to me and perhaps is a natural explanation.

Comment: The homotopy excision statement is that a homotopy pushout square is a homotopy pullback square in a certain dimensional range. (i.e. that a certain comparison map has a calculable connectivity)

Comment: One of the axioms of a homology theory is that excision is satisfied. What the homotopy excision theorem is getting at is that the **stable** homotopy groups of a space form a generalized homology theory.

Given any spectrum $E$ (which you can think of as a sequence of spaces $E_n$ with maps $\Sigma E_n \to E_{n+1}$) you can define the $E$ homology of $X$ by $E_*X=\pi_*(E \wedge X)$, where $\pi_*$ denotes the stable homotopy groups. When $E$ is the sphere spectrum this just computes that stable homotopy group of $X$.